# How to replace all occurrences in emacs?

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

I'm building a blog with org-mode publish. But I'm wanting to edit the default style given by org-mode, that edition implies wrap some tags in other tags (like divs tags). So the way I am building this is based some ideas (check the link below).

e.g. The below function it's adding a class attribute to the body tag, and it works! (The idea is based on [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36933/file-local-export-filter-functions-org-mode))

```
(defun my-html-body-onload-filter (output backend info)
"Add class to<body>  tag, if any."
(when (and (eq backend 'html)
       (string-match "<body>\n" output))
  (replace-match "<body class='uk-container-small uk-align-center uk-text-justify'> \n" nil nil output))
  )
```

So the thing I want to do right now, it's wrap img tags in other tags. I'm not a elisp programmer but I'm trying to build a function to reach some solution.
So the actual problem is this:
I have this:

```
<img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="">
```

I need to wrap img tags so I can see the next output:

```
<div uk-lightbox="animation: slide">
    <a href="images/photo.jpg">
        <img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

So far I created this little function to extract the src value:

```
(defun xe ()
  (interactive)
  (search-forward "<img src=\"")
  (defvar x-start (point))
  (search-forward "\"")
  (backward-char)
  (defvar x-end (point))
  (kill-ring-save x-start x-end)
)
```

But I feel like lost, because I don't know much about elisp... so if anyone knows how to keep going (or has the solution) to solve this problem, I would be happy:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Hello there, This was my final solution:

I created this function(Note: as you can see this function is not optimized but works, maybe I will edit this answer to post the final optimized solution):

```
(defun wrap-img-tags ()
  (setq text-to-search-1 "<img src=\"")
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (setq ntimes (count-matches text-to-search-1))

  (if (> ntimes 0)
      (cl-loop repeat ntimes do ;; this is like a for loop

       (search-forward "<img src=\"" nil t)
       (setq x-start (point))
       (search-forward "\"")
       (backward-char)
       (setq x-end (point))
       (kill-ring-save x-start x-end)
       (beginning-of-line)
       (insert (format "\n<div uk-lightbox=\"animation: slide\">
     <a href=\"%s\">\n" (car kill-ring)))
       (indent-for-tab-command)
       (forward-line)
       (insert (format "</a>\n</div>"))
                 
       )
      
      nil
      )
  )
```

**Additionally I wanted to add a class attribute on some tags**, so I *created this next function*:

```
(defun add-class-to-tag (tag class)
  "Add class attribute with the class variable value.
TAG: Tag to modify.
CLASS: Class in string form to add."
;  (interactive "sTag:\nsClass:")

  (setq text-to-search (format "<%s" tag))
  (goto-char (point-min))

  (setq does-it-have-class-attribute t)
  (cl-loop repeat (how-many text-to-search)  do ;; this is like a for loop
       
       (search-forward text-to-search)
       (setq x-start (point))

       (setq does-it-have-class-attribute (search-forward
                           "class=\""
                           (line-end-position)
                           t ; if fails return nil
                           ))

       (if (not does-it-have-class-attribute)

           (progn
         (insert (format " class=\"%s\"" class))
         (setq does-it-have-class-attribute nil)
         )

         (progn ; else
           (search-forward "\"")
           (backward-char)
           (insert (format " %s" class))

           ))
       )
  
  )
```

Finally I execute it on a pre final processor of the created html files:
(The below function idea was taken from [this blog](https://vicarie.in/posts/blogging-with-org.html))

```
(defun org-blog-publish-to-html (plist filename pub-dir)
  "Same as `org-html-publish-to-html' but modifies html before finishing."
  (let ((file-path (org-html-publish-to-html plist filename pub-dir)))
    (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file-path)
      (wrap-img-tags);; Here I'm executing the first solution
      (add-class-to-tag "h2" "uk-heading-bullet")
      (add-class-to-tag "section" "uk-card uk-card-body uk-align-center uk-text-justify")
      (add-class-to-tag "h1" "uk-h2 uk-panel uk-padding uk-background-secondary uk-light uk-margin-left uk-margin-right")
      (save-buffer)      
      (kill-buffer))
    file-path))
```

And that's it! It works :)

Additionally I would modify the **wrap-img-tags** function to wrap any kind of tags with other desired tags!

**PD**: If this answer was helpful to you, please up vote. I spent around three days researching and testing to reach to this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should not save the text. Just insert the stuff that you want.

```
    (while (search-forward "<img src=\"" nil t nil)
      
        (goto-char (match-beginning 0)) 
        (insert "<div uk-lightbox=\"animation: slide\"><a href=\"images/photo.jpg\">")
        (search-forward ">")
        (insert "</a></div>"))
```

In case you want to know more about a function use C-h f (describe-function).

Comment: The problem is that each `href` is likely to be referring to a different image file, so you have to match the pathname and then splice it in when you insert the replacement text.

Comment: Yeah exactly. It is as @NickD says. Actually I figured out how to solve this. I will comment later my solution.